# What does the full scale range in a IMU MPU9250 datasheet signify and which is better to use?

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, magnetometer, imu

I have MPU9250 IMU, which I am working on to get orientations from the sensor output data. While exploring the MPU9250 (also other sensor such as BNO055) datasheet I came across the full scale range for accel & gyro given as `±2 ±4 ±8 ±16 (g)` and `±250 ±500 ±1000 ±2000 (deg/s)`. I did not understand what it signifies, but seems important.

I tried searching online related to full scale range but did not get explanation regarding it. 
I request if someone could help me in understanding by providing good explanation or a source which I can go through, I'd really appreciate that.

Also which one would be better to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I originally wrote this answer for [this Drones.SE thread](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/1329/97) and am reposting here.</sub>

## TL;DR:

The configurable scale ranges for the accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer on the MPU-9250 IMU affect the maximum resolution and range of the reported values.

As you increase the full-scale range setting, the maximum value/rate that can be reported by the IMU before the IMU is saturated increases, but the resolution of the value/rate decreases.

---

Section 3.1 of the [datasheet for the Invensense MPU-9250](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf) has a table that states the "*Gyroscope ADC Word Length*", which represents how large the values reported over the I<sup>2</sup>C or SPI interfaces are. In this case, the gyro word length is 16 bits. A 16 bit two's complement binary number (*explained wonderfully in [this video by Ben Eater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qH4unVtJkE)*) can range from -32768 to +32767.

[image]

Take the example of the ±500 °/s full-scale range. The unit resolution of the two's complement value reported by the gyro (*aka Least Significant Bit/LSB resolution*) in the ±500 °/s full-scale range is: `32767 / 500 = 65.534 LSB/(°/s)` (*degrees per second per LSB*). This is not coincidentally labeled in the graph as the "*Sensitivity Scale Factor*" for the `FS_SEL=1` condition.